# Attempting to test a service call within subscribe() of another service call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My goal is to test whether another service's method has been called upon the success of a service call:

Service call code within component:

```
public myFunction(param: number): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.service1.service1Method(param).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.service2.service2Method({
            param1: true,
            param2: false
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.errorFunction();
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

unit test:

```
it('should call 2nd service method upon 1st service method success', fakeAsync(() => {
  
  const spyService1 = spyOn(service1, 'service1Method').and.returnValue(
    of([]])
  );
  const spyService2 = spyOn(service2, 'service2Method');

  component.myFunction(1);

  tick();

  expect(spyService1).toHaveBeenCalled();

  expect(spyService2).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    param1: true,
    param2: false
  });
}));
```

The console shows:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
Expected: {"param1": true, "param2" false}

Number of calls: 0
```

Note: all service imports and boilerplate isn't included because it shows no error for me (I'm using strong linting). There's obviously a logical error in this block of code I've written that isn't making it work.

Answer (score 0):

If the service2Method returns an observable, you need to subscribe to actually call if. In the current implementatation you never subscribed to it, so this method is never called.

You can either add another subscribe inside the existing one (which is a bad approach, but will work) or use a flattening operator (switchmap, mergemap or any other) to have a single subscribe into your function.